# Java. Поток, зависший в цикле не реагирует на if внутри него

Tags: java, jvm

Всем привет.
Изучаю Java и столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу понять, почему поток который крутится в while(true) не реагирует на if, который отслеживает изменение переменной.

Пример кода:

```
public class TestThread {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    EventThread thread = new EventThread(); // создаём объект типа поток
    thread.start(); // стартуем поток
    Thread.sleep(2000); // спим две секунды, чтобы дать потоку чуть-чуть поработать
    EventThread.setI(1); // меняем переменную i в надежде, что поток умрет
    System.out.println("main сообщает что, i уже давно = " + EventThread.getI());
}

public static class EventThread extends Thread {
    public static int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        while (true) { // в бесконечном цикле смотрим когда же изменится i
            if (i > 0) { // i меняется, но всё что ниже не исполняется
                System.out.println("я умер");
                break;
            } // если вот тут, например, написать:
            // else System.out.println("Переменная ещё не изменилась")
        }
    }

    public static void setI(int i) {
        EventThread.i = i;
    }

    public static int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}}
```

**Что я ожидаю от программы:**

1. В main создастся и запустится новый поток;
2. Main поспит две секунды и изменит переменную i на 1;
3. После main завершится
4. Тем временем новый поток зависнет в цикле и будет ждать пока переменная i не изменится (станет больше 0), после чего тоже завершится.

**Что получается на выходе:**

Происходит все, кроме завершения потока. Такое чувство, что он просто игнорирует то, что внутри цикла.

**Как получилось это исправить:**

Если добавить какое-нибудь действие внутрь цикла, например вывод в консоль или добавить else, который тоже выведет что-то в консоль, то тогда все работает так, как я и ожидаю.

**Вопрос:**

Хочется понять, почему так происходит. Что делает этот поток когда висит в цикле, почему он не реагирует на if?

Comment: Почему, он не реагирует на if, просто вы устанавливаете значение в другом потоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никто не гарантирует того, что любые изменения переменной вообще станут видимы в другом потоке.
Объявление:

```
public static volatile int i = 0;
```

в этом примере поможет добиться желаемого поведения.
Подробнее: [JMM и happens-before](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8_Java#%C2%AB%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%C2%BB), [happens-before в JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезная статья, то что искал.